# Locate Centos Dependencies

Tags: centos, dependencies, redhat

Question:

When installing a package from the yum repository:

example

> yum install numpy *opencv

it prints out a list of dependencies it has installed.

**Where can I find those dependencies?**

Comment: in the repository

Comment: Do you mean where you can find the list of dependencies for a package (such as numpy)? Or do you want to physically locate where the dependencies are located on the internet?

Comment: Yes, where can i find the list of dependencies for a package (such as numpy). and whether or not they are stored in a cache folder on centos

Answer (score 0):

The dependencies are stored within the RPM file itself.

If you have an RPM downloaded localy, you can look at it's dependencies directly:

```
rpm -qp --require /path/to/rpm
```

If you don't have the RPM locally, you can use `repoquery`:

```
repoquery --requires name-of-package
```

For example:

```
$ rpm -qp --requires python2-numpy-1.11.2-1.fc25.x86_64.rpm
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2()(64bit)
ld-linux-x86-64.so.2(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6()(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit)
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4)(64bit)
libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit)
libgfortran.so.3()(64bit)
libm.so.6()(64bit)
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libpthread.so.0()(64bit)
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)
libquadmath.so.0()(64bit)
libsatlas.so.3()(64bit)
libtatlas.so.3()(64bit)
python(abi) = 2.7
python-nose
rpmlib(CompressedFileNames) <= 3.0.4-1
rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1
rpmlib(PartialHardlinkSets) <= 4.0.4-1
rpmlib(PayloadFilesHavePrefix) <= 4.0-1
rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1
rtld(GNU_HASH)
```

Note that dependencies can be one of several different forms.

The dependencies include:

- An RPM (such as `python-nose` in the above example)
- A file (not shown above, but appears as a dependency on `/bin/bash`, for example)
- A library (such as `libpython2.7.so.1.0()(64bit)`)
- A virtual provides (such as `python(abi) = 2.7`)